# Handling different factor levels in train and test data

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, random-forest

I have a training dataset with 20 columns, all of which are factors which I have to use for training a model, I have been given a test dataset on which I have to apply my model for predictions and submit.

I was doing initial data exploration and just out of curiosity checked the levels of training data and the testing data levels since we are dealing with all categorical variables. To my dismay, most of the categories (variables) have different levels in the training and testing datasets.

For example:

```
table(train$cap.shape) #training data column levels
  b    c    f    k    x 
196    4 2356  828 2300

table(test$cap.shape) #test data 
 b    f    s    x 
256  796   32 1356
```

Here I have an extra category `s` in the test data set. How can I handle these cases? The extra category `c` in the training is very low, so I was thinking to merge that factor with another factor based on how its distribution is with dependent variables, but I am stuck on how to handle the extra level in the test set.

More examples:

```
table(train$odor) #train
  c    f    m    n    p    s    y 
 189 2155   36 2150    2  576  576

table(test$odor) #test
  a    c    f    l    n    p 
400    3    5  400 1378  254
```

In this column we have two extra levels in the test set with a substantial number of instances in the test dataset. How can I handle these discrepancies?

```
table(train$sColour) #train
    b    h    k    n    o    r    w    y 
   48 1627  700  753   48   72 2388   48

table(test$sColour) #test
    h    k    n    u 
    5 1172 1215   48
```

Here we have an extra factor `u`.

Should I first build a model just on the training set and find the important predictors and then worry about the factor levels?

Comment: You can merge the test and training sets back together with rbind() and then resplit into test and train sets using the createDataPartition() function from the caret package for a stratified random sampling.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: For most random forest/tree algorithms, new levels are treated as missing. There are several ways to handle missing values: using surrogate splits, imputation, or simply randomly picking a child node.  I don't think merging factors is a good idea, but there's a lot of research on how trees should handle missing values.